# typeset restrictions: standard notation gives error message

Tags: amsmath

Although including the necessary math packages I can can, for whatever reason, not write

```
$\left. f \right|_x$
```

to typeset a function restriction. The following error messages are produced
[image]

What could be reasons causing this error? The class template has thousond of lines of code, so I can not upload it here.

Comment: The error you are showing is associated with the `\let` not with the bit of maths.

Comment: you are probably using `\MakeShortVerb|`  somewhere (from the shortvrb package).

Comment: Of course typing `f|_x` would be much simpler and wouldn't add unwanted space.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, this package is not included in the class. I guess the problem is related to the vertical bar, because $ | \tilde{u} | $ gives the error "\tilde only allowed in math mode". If I remove the two bars, everything works. Does this bring us closer to the issue? It seems that the bar leaves the math environment which would also explain  the error in my original question

Comment: In fact, if I supersede | by \verb, the error messages are resolved. Anyway, what could have caused the issues?

Comment: well something redefines `|`. You will have to find it.

Comment: @egreg `$f|_x$ `  errors after `\MakeShortVerb|`  too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course…

Comment: Running the code given in `article` class using only `amsmath` (actually not needed to compile the code) returns no errors. So I suggest to look into the packages loaded and try to isolate the one causing the issue.

Comment: Inside the class template there is a bunch of packages being loaded. Put those into a new document class like `article` (or the document class your template is based on) and just put in the line you gave us. Then comment out each package at a team to see when the error is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recently polished crystal ball tells me that you're using the `sn-jnl` class for Springer Nature.

This class, for inexplicable and unfathomable reasons, loads the `program` package.

Use `\vert` instead of `|` for the restriction, but note that

```
f\vert_x
```

is better than using `\left` and `\right`. For the absolute value, use `\lvert...\rvert` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: Ooh, that nasty oldie... though IIRC at some point the author introduced `\normalbaroutside` to... erm, let us say "correct" his inexplicable and unfathomable choice.

Comment: @campa It's not really about `program` (although I've never understood what it's for and its complicated syntax), but about Springer inflicting this package to users of its classes.